# Is there a way to extract data from django templates except the POST method

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates, http-post

In one of the pages of my website i m trying to create two buttons save and delete. Save as the name suggests saves the data filled into form in my database. Delete deletes this data. I want to access these two buttons separately in my views.py file but the only way i know to detect user input is checking if request.method == 'POST'. But in the case of both the save and delete button POST request is going to be made. How can i differentiate between the click of delete and save button so that i can write different code for each?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `name` tag in the button to differentiate between POST operations.

For example:

```html
<button name="delete">Delete</button>
```

And use in condition in view:

```py
if "delete" in request.POST:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two separated form, and submit them by ajax seems the easiest way.

**view.py**

Create 2 views. One for add/update data, and second one for delete data.

```
def submit_view(...):
    if request.POST:
        # add data (if form.is_valid, and more)

def delete_view(...):
    if request.POST:
        # delete data (if form.is_valid, and more)
```

**template**

Now add two separated forms in template, and submit them by using ajax.

```
<form action="/submit" id="submit_form">
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit_button">
</form> 

<form action="/delete" id="delete_form">
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="delete" id="delete_button">
</form> 

<script>
    $('#submit_button').on('click',function(){$('#submit_form').submit();});
    $('#delete_button').on('click',function(){$('#delete_form').submit();});    
</script>
```

Comment: sir i got it but can you plz tell me why $ sign

Comment: Its becouse of jQuery. If you don't like it try vanila JS.

Try someting like below


    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('submit_form').submit();
        });

        document.getElementById('delete_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('delete_form').submit();
        });
    </script>